# How to save extracted PDF data into Word file?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

How can I save the data extracted from the file in Word, I tried some techniques that I found in the forum but they all concern opening a file in excel and notepad to save in word, I didn't find any suggestion of how to save the data extracted from PDF.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader


Conteudo = []

reader = PdfReader(r'C:\Users\felip\Downloads\Edital 274 2022 Estágio Direito.pdf')
number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)

for i in range(number_of_pages):
    page = reader.pages[i]
    text = page.extract_text()
    print(text)
```

Comment: What is this World?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to save it into a Word file?

Comment: Word, I made the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import docx
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

pdf_text = extract_text('path/to/pdf')

doc = docx.Document()

doc.add_paragraph(pdf_text)

doc.save('path/to/new/word/document')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: What is `parse_pdf_data()`?

Comment: without success, I installed pdfminer but it doesn't load high_level (Import "pdfminer.high_level" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports)

"parse_pdf_data" is not definedPylancereportUndefinedVariable

Comment: @Felipe don't need to install a new library for _Pdf_ manipulation if you already have one. Look just at the [`docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) part of this answer (maybe also with `doc.add_page_break()`)

Answer (score 0):

Your best results will be direct PDF to DocX translation,

Lower Left is the PDF,   -   Lower Right is what You may expect at best from Rich Text

Upper image is Adobe Conversion into DocX same as MSWord from Acrobat.

The simplest method is to program Word to import PDF and save as DocX as Adobe did.

roughly open the file with a macro to save into DocX but you will need to write and save that macro in your own Word(s)
`MsWord C:\Users\felip\Downloads\Edital 274 2022 Estágio Direito.pdf`

[image]